# Custom rack 8-12 drive NAS build backplane support?

Tags: server, nas

Looking for advice on building a 8/12 bay NAS server.

I'm considering building a custom 2U rack mount NAS server build, and found the majority of the parts I need, but I don't understand if the motherboard/OS(*FreeNAS*) will support the barebone case backplane.

Are backplanes standardized enough that I can just plug into a standard motherboard, or do I need a specific interface card that I need to buy?

(Currently looking at a 8/12 bay NAS case from INNOVISION via aliexpress

Comment: Make it a condition of sale that it does. If the sales rep quails at putting that on record, it doesn't.

Comment: Looks like sata backplanes are just straight pass-through, so it appears that standard sata connectors are used: https://www.ebay.com/itm/SUPERMICRO-SAS846TQ-SAS-SATA-4U-BACKPLANE-BOARD-24x-3-5/173749311620